# how to read file name with two variable parts

Tags: python, regex

There is a folder with multiple Excel files in it. They are named in a systematic way. Like below:

```
a_b_12_2021043036548.xlsx
```

- The `a_b_12_`  part is fixed
- `20210430` changes every day
- `36548` also change every day, and there is no rule for it, other than that it's always five digits

I have to read this Excel file every day from another script, and save it as a dataframe. How can I do this?

I tried the following lines but failed

```py
datetime_format = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 30)  # I just want to change the date here to read the related excel

x = datetime_format.strftime("%Y%m%d")
file1 = r'C:/report/FG/a_b_12_' + x + * + '.xlsx'  #failed

file1 = r'C:/report/FG/a_b_12_' + x + r'[\d\]+' + '.xlsx'   #failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
from glob import glob
pattern = rf'C:/report/FG/a_b_12_{x}*.xlsx'
matched_files = glob(pattern)
```

Assuming your assumption holds, and there is indeed exactly one such file, `matched_files[0]` will be it.

Comment: I got matched_files = [] and obviously  matched_files[0] returend this error; IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The code should be correct — or at least I can't find why it would not work. Check the pattern (`print (pattern)`), check the current directory (`print(os.getcwd())`), make sure the pattern is correct and matches the file on your disk.

Comment: I am getting matched_files = C:/report/FG\a_b_12_20210430.xlsx  so when i run the pd.read_csv(matched_files)  this error comes up  ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>

Comment: The result you get from `glob` is always a list which you will have to loop over or extract the resulting file name from. See the last sentence in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime_format = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 30)  
x=datetime_format.strftime("%Y%m%d")
dailyrunningnumber = 36548 

file1 = 'C:/report/FG/a_b_12_{}.xlsx'.format(x)
file1 = 'C:/report/FG/a_b_12_{}{}.xlsx'.format(x, str(dailyrunningnumber))
```

Edited:

```
import glob

# listing all xlsx absolute dirs
f_glob = rf'C:/report/FG/a_b_12_*.xlsx'
f_names = glob.glob(f_glob)
print(f_names)
```

Comment: thank you @hongkail, but the dailyrunningnumber change every time, always a 5 digits number but not the same

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second part is always a date, and that you know the date, just add a glob after that.

In Python, `*` in isolation is multiplication; the glob in your code needs to be a quoted string, like `"*"` or `'*'`, just like you quote the rest of the file name.

```py
import datetime
import glob

datetime_format = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 30)
x = datetime_format.strftime("%Y%m%d")
matching_files = = glob.glob('C:/report/FG/a_b_12_' + x + '*.xlsx')
for file1 in matching_files:
    # ...
```

If you are certain that the glob will always match a single file, of course, just use `file1 = matching_files[0]`

The temporary variables are nice for legibility, but really not particularly useful, so this can be refactored to

```py
datetime_format = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 30)
for file1 glob.glob('C:/report/FG/a_b_12_' + datetime_format.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '*.xlsx'):
    # ...
```

You need an `r'...'` string when your string contains literal backslashes, but since you are using forward slash for the Windows directory separator (which is altogether more convenient anyway) I removed the `r`.

If you really want a regex solution, try

```py
import re
import os

pattern = re.compile(r'^a_b_12_(\d+{8})(\d{5})\.xls$')
for file in os.scandir('C:/report/FG/'):
    matched = pattern.match(file.name):
    if matched:
        file1 = file.name
        date = matched.group(1)
        suffix = matched.group(2)
        break  # or whatever
```